# Argument in fuction call inside function definition is not being replaced in Maxima

Tags: arguments, maxima, function-call

## The problem

Consider the following script written in [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)

```
$ cat main.max
foo(a) ::= block(
    if a = 0 then return(0) else return(1)
)$

bar(a) ::= block(
    return(foo(a))
)$

foo(0);
bar(0);
```

Executing this script yields to

```
$ cat main.max | maxima --very-quiet
                                       0
                                       1
```

## The question

Isn't it supposed that calling `foo` by itself results the same as if it is called from another function (in this scenario, `bar`)?

Here there is another example

```
$ cat main.max
foo(a) ::= block(disp(a))$
bar(a) ::= block(foo(a))$

foo(0)$
bar(0)$
$ cat main.max | maxima --very-quiet
                                       0

                                       a
```

In other words: Why isn't `maxima` replacing the argument that is passed to `bar` in the `foo` function call which is located within `bar`?

## Additional context

This is the version that I'm currently using

```
$ maxima --version
Maxima 5.43.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::=` defines a function which quotes (does not evaluate) its arguments, and the return value of the function is evaluated by the caller. Such a function is conventionally called a "macro" for historical reasons.

I think you want an ordinary, argument-evaluating function, which is defined by `:=`. Try substituting `:=` for `::=` in your function definitions -- when I try that, I get 0 for `bar(0)` as expected.

Macros are useful, but in relatively narrow circumstances. I think ordinary functions are much more common than macros.

As an aside, in the functions which you have shown, `block` and `return` are unneeded. My advice is to just leave them out and make the functions more succinct and therefore more clear. E.g.

```
foo(a) := if a = 0 then 0 else 1;
bar(a) := foo(a);
```

Finally, note that `=` is only literal comparison, not equivalence; equivalence is tested with `equal`. E.g. suppose `x` is not otherwise defined. Then `is(x = 0)` yields `false`, but `is(equal(x, 0))` yields the expression `equal(x, 0)`. Depending on what you're doing, one or the other might be appropriate.